# header file error

Tags: c++, windows, visual-studio

При подключении одного header файла к двум файлам *.cpp выдаёт ошибки:

```
Ошибка  LNK2005 "float forMyForm::fltBalance" (?fltBalance@forMyForm@@3MA) єцх юяЁхфхыхэ т MyForm.obj   
Ошибка  LNK2005 "float forMyForm::fltPlus" (?fltPlus@forMyForm@@3MA) єцх юяЁхфхыхэ т MyForm.obj Project1    
Ошибка  LNK1169 юсэрЁєцхэ ьэюуюъЁрЄэю юяЁхфхыхээ√щ ёшьтюы - юфшэ шыш сюыхх  Project1
```

header файл, который подключается:

```
#pragma once

namespace forMyForm
{
    float fltBalance;
    float fltPlus = 1;
}
```

UPD: Этот вопрос пометили как дубликат вопроса, от которого данный отличается. Здесь проблема не в считывании с сайта, а в подключении файла заголовка, имеющий в себе переменную, которая нужна в двух файлах *.cpp

Comment: Нарушение One Definition Rule.

Comment: Ответ по ссылке действительно нечитабелен. Однако ошибка классическая - во так вот определять переменные в заголовочном файле нельзя. Можно только если с `inline`.

Comment: Спасибо большое за ответ. Можете, пожалуйста, навести пример, как нужно правильно объявить переменную, чтобы можно было её использовать не только в одном *.cpp файле?